# How to get rid of pulseaudio messages in syslog?

Tags: pulseaudio, syslog

I have a lot of messages in `syslog` regarding pulseaudio, but the server is in Azure Cloud.
I can't get rid of these messages.

**I don't need sound on this server**

```
pulseaudio[56093]: Failed to open cookie file '/usr/a/usr/gun5/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
pulseaudio[56093]: Failed to load authentication key '/usr/a/usr/gun5/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
pulseaudio[56093]: Failed to open cookie file '/usr/a/usr/gun5/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
```

Comment: can you not uninstall pulseaudio?

Comment: Did not tried, but the service does not exist!

Comment: what do you mean "does not exist"? clearly it exists if it's leaving logs in syslog